# How to include exe file in C++ builder?

Tags: c++, windows, resources, c++builder

I put exe file in project, and from button click execute those exe, and that's work fine. Also   my configuration is define to be portable and standalone application by putting this two options:

1. C++ Linker->Dynamics RTL = false
2. Packages->Runtim packages->Build with runtime packages = unchecked

**edited:**

But when I copy those application and try to use it on another computer, it wan't execute exe file from project. That is because exe file which is included in project is not in the same directory as application.

So question is how to real include exe in project, not just put the location to them? How to configure application that can be use on another computer like on mine?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "put exe file in project"? Are you talking about the executable that C++ Builder generates for you? Have you tried running it with ProcessMonitor by Sysinternals (or a similar tool) to check whether it's missing any DLLs or the like?

Comment: It's mean file that is already compiled (stand alone simple console program), no I didn't try other methods.

Comment: Probably the very problem has to do with that exe demanding some DLL's that are present on your computer but not on other computers. The problem will be solved adding that DLL's to your distribution bundle, as well. For example, a tool for this could be http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: thnx for answer but I find out that project is just show the location of the file, but not real include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if this will work but Have you tried to include the exe file by including it in a res file, awhile ago i added some wav's to a res file and they got included in my application, i was then able to use the onclick event of a button to play them.